# Wrong targetContentOffset in scrollViewWillEndDragging

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have plain scrollView with directionalLockEnabled = YES

When I try to scroll in one direction ( let it be X), i always receive almost right result at X coordinate, but strange offset on Y.

Here is my delegate method:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity
          targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset
{
    NSLog(@"current end: %f %f", _scrollView.contentOffset.x, _scrollView.contentOffset.y);
    NSLog(@"velocity: %f %f", velocity.x, velocity.y);
    NSLog(@"will end: %f %f", targetContentOffset->x, targetContentOffset->y);
}
```

And this is the result:

```
2013-08-06 10:46:59.310 TestScroll[999:c07] current end: 255.000000 778.000000
2013-08-06 10:46:59.312 TestScroll[999:c07] velocity: 0.533821 -0.000000
2013-08-06 10:46:59.312 TestScroll[999:c07] will end: 517.000000 773.000000
```

As you can see, current offset is 778 and velocity is 0. So how can it be that view will stop at content offset 773.

Checked on 6.1 iPad and 5.0, 6.1 simulator